# C# how to stop a control's event

Tags: c#

I have an .aspx page that has a page_load as follows:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name != "")
    {
        ....
    }
    else
    {
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
        return;
    }
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ....
}
```

The issue I am noticing is that when the user clicks the submit button it goes though the `Page_Load` (goes though the else) and then tries to run though the protected void `btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`.

Is there a way to make it redirect to the login page and not continue to the next void?

Comment: Um, Check for `Page.IsPostBack`? (Your question is a bit ambiguous though...)

Comment: What do you mean by "next void"?

Comment: IsPostBack is not the issue. I want the code to stop running after the redirect and not continue to btnSubmit_Click

Comment: I've read it about 4 times now, still not any clearer. However, I _believe_ OP is saying they want to stop processing in the Page_Load (so it doesn't go Page_Load->ClickEvent). I would say `Response.End` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! Response.End() did the trick.

Comment: @BringQBasicBack note that this is the normal page life cycle!

Comment: If the user isn't authenticated how did they load the page the first time to have a button to click in order to be sending a button click postback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **NOT** an issue. This is the normal [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Controls events fire right after the `Page_Load` event.

Note that the [FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.redirecttologinpage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method does not end the request by calling `HttpResponse.End`. This means that code that follows the RedirectToLoginPage method call will run.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to stop further processing from within the `Page_Load` (which I *believe* is your intention with `return`):

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (/*I want to kill processing*/)
    {
        // Method one:
        Response.End(); // Though admittedly ugly

        // Method two:
        this.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

        return; // return as normal (short-circuit)
    }
}
```